# How can I, using Knockout, make a div only viewable when a value from a dropdown is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

When I select "USB Access Request" from the dropdown which is pulled from a SHarepoint list, I want to view a div.

Dropdown

```
Application: 
                <select data-bind="value: $data.selectedApp, options: $parent.applications, optionsText: 'ApplicationName', optionsCaption: 'Choose an Application'" style="width: 32px" name="Application list" id="dataBox">
                </select>
    <div name="main">
```

Div I want to show

```
<div name="main">
        <input type="checkbox" /> Tick this box if there is an end date for the 
        permissions.
    </div>
    <div class='other' name='other' title='other' style='display:none;'>  
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
    </div>
```

I have removed the script I had as it was completely wrong but will add it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind the value of the dropdown to a view model observable, like `selectedApp`. Make sure it's defined in your view model like `self.selectedApp = ko.observable();`.

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedApp, options: $parent.applications, optionsText: 'ApplicationName', optionsCaption: 'Choose an Application'" style="width: 32px" name="Application list" id="dataBox">
</select>
```

Then use the visible binding to show the div only when selectedApp has a value:

```
<!-- ko visible: selectedApp -->
<div name="main">
    <input type="checkbox" /> Tick this box if there is an end date for the permissions.
</div>
<div class='other' name='other' title='other' style='display:none;'>  
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I just realized how little info I gave you, anyway I added in more details but  Ill try out your answer now. thanks,